CSS Создание иконки через псевдоэлемент
Подскажите, как можно создать некий класс, присваивая который данному <div> можно б было получить изображение похожее на это.

у меня есть изначальная болванка.


body{
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #090C09;
}


.gr {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  
  
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  outline: 1px solid rgba(30, 32, 29, 0.4);
  outline-offset: 3px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(#0e130f 2px, transparent 2px),
  linear-gradient(90deg, #0e130f 2px, transparent 2px);
  background-size: 2px 2px;
  background-color: #0B100A;


  box-shadow: inset 0 0 40px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
<div class="gr"></div>



Но вот как реализовать этот "крест" при помощи CSS что-то не понимаю. Может кто-то может показать? Желательно через :before :after
/// Добавил пример с SVG


body{
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #090C09;
}


.gr {
width: 60px;
height: 60px;
position: relative;
box-sizing: border-box;
border: 2px solid #000;
outline: 1px solid rgba(30, 32, 29, 0.4);
outline-offset: 3px;
background-image: 
  linear-gradient(#0e130f 2px, transparent 2px),
  linear-gradient(90deg, #0e130f 2px, transparent 2px);
background-size: 60px 60px;
background-color: #0B100A;
box-shadow: inset 0 0 40px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
  }
  
  .gr_new:after{
content:"";
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
z-index: 1;
background-image:  url('data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns=%22http://www.w3.org/2000/svg%22 viewBox=%220 0 60 60%22 style=%22enable-background:new 0 0 60 60%22 xml:space=%22preserve%22%3E%3Cstyle%3E.st1,.st2%7Bfill:none;stroke-miterlimit:10%7D.st1%7Bstroke:%23283028;stroke-width:4%7D.st2%7Bstroke:%23000%7D%3C/style%3E%3Cg%3E%3Cpath class=%22st1%22 d=%22m0 0 60 60M0 61 60 0%22/%3E%3Cpath class=%22st2%22 d=%22m1.5-1.5 29 29M29.5 32.5l29 29M-1.5 1.5l29 29M32.5 29.5l29 29M-1.5 59.5l29-29M1.5 62.5l29-30M32.6 30.1 61.5 1.5M30.5 27.5l28-29%22/%3E%3C/g%3E%3C/svg%3E');
}
<div class="gr gr_new"></div>




берешь before и after и поворачиваешь на 45 градусов - вот тебе и крест

Как я понял, проблема не в самом кресте, а в тех градиентах, которые присутствуют на изображении. Действительно, если в графическом редакторе повысить яркость, то становится очевидно, что рисунок очень даже непростой. С помощью CSS можно достичь похожего результата, но боюсь, что код будет "весить" столько же, сколько сама картинка в PNG.

Попробуй другую картинку примера сделать, конкретно сейчас в маленьком виде даже крест тяжело разглядеть

@UModeL, чисто технически ничего не мешает нарисовать такую svg и поставить ее фоном

Добавь описание что не так с вариантов в svg? Растянуть его можно как угодно, в том числе чтобы доходил до границ

Так выглядит ваше исходное изображение (увеличенное в 5 раз и осветлённое на 150%):

На этой основе получилось следующее:


.gr {
  /* Масштаб --> */ font-size: 16px;
  position: relative;
  width: 23.25em; height: 23.25em;
  background-color: #272f24;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0.1875em 1.3125em #1a1f19, inset 0 0 0.875em 1.875em #000, inset 0 0 7.5em 5.625em #0b1009;
  /* Раскомментировать и настроить filter: brightness(.3); */
}
.gr::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0;
  background: center / 21.875em 21.875em linear-gradient(45deg, #0000 calc(50% - 0.75em), #262d24 calc(50% - 0.375em) calc(50% + 0.375em), #0000 calc(50% + 0.75em)) no-repeat, center / 21.875em 21.875em linear-gradient(-45deg, #0000 calc(50% - 0.75em), #262d24 calc(50% - 0.375em) calc(50% + 0.375em), #0000 calc(50% + 0.75em)) no-repeat, center / 20.5em 20.5em linear-gradient(45deg, #0000 calc(50% - 1.5em), #0008 calc(50% - 0.875em) calc(50% + 0.875em), #0000 calc(50% + 1.5em)) no-repeat, center / 20.5em 20.5em linear-gradient(-45deg, #0000 calc(50% - 1.5em), #0008 calc(50% - 0.875em) calc(50% + 0.875em), #0000 calc(50% + 1.5em)) no-repeat;
  --mask: center / 22.5em 22.5em radial-gradient(circle, #000f 14.375em, #0000 15.3125em) no-repeat;
  -webkit-mask: var(--mask); mask: var(--mask);
  /* Дополнительное размытие filter: blur(0.125em); */
}

body { background-color: #090C09; }
<div class="gr"></div>




Крест представляет из себя две повернутые линии.
Для поворота можно воспользоваться функцией rotate
Сами линии можно сделать обычными элементами, либо псевдоэлементами: достаточно указать ширину и высоту.
Далее просто определиться с background у элементов.
Для корректного расположение по центру стоит добавить position:absolute
В итоге может получиться так:


body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #090C09;
}

.gr {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  outline: 1px solid rgba(30, 32, 29, 0.4);
  outline-offset: 3px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(#0e130f 2px, transparent 2px), linear-gradient(90deg, #0e130f 2px, transparent 2px);
  background-size: 2px 2px;
  background-color: #0B100A;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 40px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.gr::before,
.gr::after {
  content: '';
  background: red;
  height: 1px;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}

.gr::before {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.gr::after {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}


}
<div class="gr"></div>




Нет, это не то что я ищу. На картинке "крест" имеет тени по боках + в середине эти тени не пересикаються, а на краях выходят за пределы квадрата но ровно на столько что б создать эффект перекрытия. Я думал, что данный элемент можно создать через  background: conic-gradient , но пока, не получаеться. Так же пробовал SVG, но из-за малых размеров края вылязят за пределы фигури...

@BlackStar1991, ширину можно выставить какую угодно - чтобы выходила за пределы, чтобы не выходила. Всегда можно сделать обычную картинку в качестве фона. Добавь пример своего svg чтобы было видно что именно не так у тебя отобразилось

Добавил. Реализация, как на фото пока не получаеться
